# How can I find CiviCases that have no Case Contact via the CiviCRM UI

Tags: civicase

Title kind of says it. I found some Cases with no Case Contact in the db. Tried Find Case and Case Reports etc but not sure I can see a way, even when knowing the Case ID, that I can find the problem Case (and hopefully also 'fix' it)

I know I can probably resolve this in the db, but ideally I shouldn't have to.

If i know the Case ID then perhaps API Explorer will let me assign a new Case Contact. But first I need to be able to tell there are some problem Cases.

Answer (score 1):

select c.id from civicrm_case c left join civicrm_case_contact cc on cc.case_id = c.id where cc.contact_id is null

then

insert into civicrm_case_contact (case_id, contact_id) values (1,2)

where 1 and 2 are the real numbers

---

OR it is possible with search kit:

[image]

Comment: indeed. that is where I was heading but in the interest of the wider group of civicrm users I was wanting to confirm if there was a UI approach, and if not, and if there should be, then we might take a look at what changes would be needed to make this viable.

Comment: You might be able to do it with search kit, but this situation shouldn't happen, so I'd be more interested in figuring out why the foreign keys allow it and what to do about that.

Comment: it is possible these were created in webform hence the 'how can it be created with no case contact' may not be a pure civi question

Comment: Or maybe "permanently deleted" contacts creating orphan cases, but if so, then that seems an issue with foreign keys in the database.